# Get CPU Usage In Percentage Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to get cpu details in percentage like i wanted to run a script, if cpu is less than 70% then run the script else stop the script.. because script takes too much load when it runs and i can't figure out the existing way of getting cpu usage `chrome.system.cpu.getInfo`
in simple word i wanted to do like this:

```
if(chrome.system.cpu.usage<70)
{
startScript();
}
else
{
stopScript();
}
```

But in chrome extension i'm feeling a bit lost.

Comment: See related topic about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473134/chrome-system-cpu-api-usage

Comment: i already checked it, i think i need a call method for content script right? because to check cpu i need to create a external cpu check js file then i can execute that script i'm i right or i'm missing something?

Comment: Yes you will need to add the `system.cpu` permissions in your manifest file and create a function that calls the chrome extension api endpoint `chrome.system.cpu.getInfo`. Then have that function perform the desired calculations to return the cpu usage, see: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_cpu and my previous link.

This function can either be placed in a background script and listen for events by using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or in a content script if you are running without a background script in your extension.